WiX Installer use .exe instead of .dll for installation
I am working on developing a SignalR Hub as a Windows service.
However, I am encountering issues with the installer as it uses the Project.dll to initialize the service instead of the Project.exe.
To test this, I used the CMD commands "sc create TestServer binPath=" to create a service that uses the Project.exe and another one that uses the Project.dll.
With the exe, I can start the service, but with the dll, I face the same problem as with the installer. Therefore, I suspect that the installer is causing the issue.
The code for the installation is as follows:
<Component Id="SDCommunicationHub">
    <File Id="SDCommunicationHub" Source="$(var.SDCommunicationHub.TargetPath)" />
    <ServiceInstall Type="ownProcess" Name="SDCommunicationHub" DisplayName=" SDCommunicationHub" Description="Communication between PC and server" Start="auto" Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]" ErrorControl="normal" Vital="yes" />
    <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="SDCommunicationHub" Wait="no" />
    <ServiceConfig ServiceName="SDCommunicationHub" OnInstall="yes" DelayedAutoStart="yes" />
</Component>

I am grateful for any help, maybe I am making a mistake and it's not possible this way.

In your File tag, is your Source pointing to the exe? Wix should generate a msi file in the bin folder of the installer project. You don't need to use the cmd prompts to install, simply double-click on the msi file.

Starting the installer with the msi file brings me the Error, that i have sufficient priviliges to start the service. --> YES i checked my priviliges! :-D
I tested it with the cmd prompts and found out, with the exe file the service works but with the dll file the service does not start.

It's probably your AccountName in the ServiceInstall tag. Check the app logs inside Event Viewer. The Account should be something like NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM.

I don't think it has anything to do with the account name. I used the same installer code for another service, and it works fine. I tried removing the autostart, and then the installation works. However, when starting, I get the error:
The service "SDCommunicationHub" did not start due to the following error:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Make sure you have all of your dlls in the package that are required to run the app.

I have, like i said, i can start the Program as a Console Application from the exe. Also i can create the service with the exe.
But the installer fails
